# Dark matter and supersymmetric particles

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model

Is there a possibility to consider supersymmetric particles of fermions and bosons as the unknown dark matter?

Comment: Maybe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightest_Supersymmetric_Particle#Lightest_Supersymmetric_Particle_as_a_dark_matter_candidate), but... (https://atlas.cern/updates/physics-briefing/strong-constraints-supersymmetric-dark-matter)

Comment: It is the neutralino that is a good candidate for dark matter from supersymmetric particles. https://cms.cern/physics/detecting-dark-matter

Answer (score 0):

Several supersymmetric models contain a 'Lightest supersymmetric particle' that makes a good candidate for dark matter (e.g. neutralino in the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model).
But we know for sure that dark matter particle cannot carry an electromagnetic or color charge, otherwise we would have detected them by now. That is why for instance dark matter cannot be made of selectrons of squarks, which carry the same charges as their Standard Model partners, namely electrons and quarks.